# $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has eigenvalues in $\mathbb{Z}$ with at least 3 different eigenvalues. $\det(A)^n = 5^4$, find $A$'s eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\newcommand{\adj}{\text{adj}}$

The question as it appeared in the first place: $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that all $A$'s eigenvalues are in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $A$ has at least 3 different eigenvalues.
Let $B$ be the matrix results in making the next row operations upon $A$ : $R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2$ , $R_2 \rightarrow 5R_2$ , $R_4 \rightarrow R_4-16R_2$.

Given that $\det((B\cdot \adj(A))^{-1}) = -\frac{1}{5^5}$ Find $A's$ eigenvalues.

So: $$\begin{align}\det((B\cdot \adj(A))^{-1}) = -\frac{1}{5^5} &\Rightarrow \det((B\cdot \adj(A))) = -5^5 \\&\Rightarrow \det(B)\cdot \det(A)^{n-1}= -5^5 \\&\Rightarrow -1\cdot 5\cdot \det(A)\cdot \det(A)^{n-1} = -5^5 \\&\Rightarrow \det(A)^n = 5^4\end{align}$$
This is where I got to the question represented in the title.
I don't know anything else about $A$, I got few examples for $A$ which satisfies the conditions: $\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,5), \text{diag}(1,1,-1,-5)...$ 
I don't see how do the conditions determine $A's$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $n$ doing here?

Comment: @xbh: Apparently the exercise doesn't even fix the dimension of the matrix -- though the specified row operations only make sense if $n\ge 4$.

Comment: Your example $A$s satisfy $\det(A) = 5^4$, not $\det(A)^4 = 5^4$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for clarification. Somehow I did not under the question in the OP...

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Good point -- but still both $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1,5)$ and $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,-5)$ would seem to fit the requirements?

Comment: @Henning:  I agree that those examples are more problematic

Comment: @JasonDeVito absolutely right, i'll correct it.

Comment: What about $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,5)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(-1,-1,1,-5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the eigenvalues are all integers, their product $\det(A)$ is an integer.  What are the divisors of $5^4$?

EDIT: Use the fact that $n \ge 4$.

Comment: The  possible solutions are $(-1,-1,1,5)$ and $(-1,1,1,-5)$.

Comment: Or $(1,1,-1,5)$

Comment: @amsmath or $(1,-1,-1,-5)$.

Comment: Exactly. So, $n=4$ and there are four solutions.